# How to customize vhost file for a WHM-CPanel host?

Tags: apache, cpanel, virtualhost, whm

I want to change the document root for a particular host.

Currently the setting for the host is :

```
<VirtualHost 123.164.132.142:80>
  ServerName abc.com
  ServerAlias mail.abc.com www.abc.com
  DocumentRoot /home/abc/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@abc.com
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/abc.com combined
  <IfModule log_config_module>
    <IfModule logio_module>
      CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/abc.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  ## User abc # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        UserDir enabled
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
 # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
 # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
 #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
 <IfModule include_module>
   <Directory "/home/abc/public_html">
     SSILegacyExprParser On
   </Directory>
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule suphp_module>
   suPHP_UserGroup abc abc
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
   <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
     SuexecUserGroup abc abc
   </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule ruid2_module>
   RMode config
   RUidGid abc abc
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
   # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
   #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
   AssignUserID abc abc
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule alias_module>
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/abc/public_html/cgi-bin/
 </IfModule>
 Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/abc/abc.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to create a conf file in `/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2_4/abc/abc.com/` to change the document root to `.../public_html/public` then run `/scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --all-users` to rebuild httpd.conf and restart Apache. However, I don't think it's taking effect because files in `public_html` are still accessable by the world.

What's the correct way to customize settings for the host?

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom template that affects how cPanel & WHM builds entries for only a single virtual host, you'll have to perform the following steps:

Create a copy of one or more of the following files:

```
Apache 2.2 with SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_2/ssl_vhost.default
Apache 2.4 with SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ssl_vhost.default
Apache 2.2 without SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_2/vhost.default
Apache 2.4 without SSL — /var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/vhost.default
```

Rename the new copy of the file to one of the following filenames:

**vhost.local** (Use this filename if you copied the vhost.default file)

**ssl_vhost.local** (Use this filename if you copied the ssl_vhost.default file)

Edit the new file to make changes to your virtual host configuration.
Move the new file to any other directory (let's say **/opt** for this example). So let's say you will have the new template as `/opt/new-vhost-template`

Use the following script to add the necessary information to the data structure:

```
perl -MYAML::Syck -e \
'my $hr = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($ARGV[0]);$hr->{$ARGV[1]} = $ARGV[2];YAML::Syck::DumpFile($ARGV[0],$hr);' \
/var/cpanel/userdata/$username/$domainname custom_vhost_template_ap2 /opt/new-vhost-template
```

That should do the trick!

*Please keep in mind that the above example applies to a specific vhost for a cpanel user/account and does not apply to all the vhosts on the server.*